# If statement not working as expected

Tags: bash

In my if and then statement, the script doesn't evaluate my if condition and no matter what always jumps to else condition, May be issue with my syntax:

```
val=$(cat cp_a.txt)
echo $val
if [[ $val == 0 ]]; then
echo "B is active"
else
echo "A is active"
fi
unset val
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ssm-user@~]$ ./test.sh
0
A is active
```

OUTPUT OF CAT file:

```
[ssm-user@~]$ cat cp_a.txt
0
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
 B is ACTIVE
```

Comment: What is the output of `od -c cp_a.txt`?

Comment: The command substitution will remove any trailing newlines from the file, so if the contents are e.g. `0<nl><nl>`, you get just the `0`. But it doesn't remove any trailing spaces or such, so `0<sp><nl>` gets you `0<sp>`, not the same as just `0`. And if your file came from a Windows machine and you have CRLF line endings there, the carriage return is not removed and `0<cr>` is not the same as `0`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but as you can when I cat the file, its displaying 0 no other characters as part of the output which we are passing to the variable. I do not understand why it still over looks the if statement

Comment: Again, please post the output of `od -c cp_a.txt`. It may surprise you.